# How to retrieve/set path to a Linked OLE Object in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm setting up a Database which will has OLE Objects (AutoCAD Drawings). I've limited users to only be able to Link OLE Objects (instead of embedding them) in order to prevent overloading the tables with duplicates of the files.

My problem at this time is that when users browse for a file in a network drive, they input a relative link (W:\Department\Files\Drawings\NewPart.dwg) instead of the UNC (\\Server\Volume\Department\Files\Drawings\NewPart.dwg). I found code to change a drive letter into its UNC counterpart even for users with differing drive letters for the same drive, so that's a non-issue.

What I'd like to do is either:

- Force Access, when browsing for a file, to input the UNC path; or
- Retrieve the path from the OLE Object saved in the table (so I can change it to UNC via code), and then being able to set a new path for the OLE Object.

Am I going about this wrong? I've tried a bunch of different code-snippets found throughout several websites and can't seem to get it right. I'm also not a software developer, I'm a mechanical engineer, so I probably have the basics down wrong. If there's a better way to do this, please point it out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: VBA can open Windows FileDialog with start location that uses network UNC: `.InitialFileName = "\\servername\Users\June\Forums"`. When you have specific code with issue, ask question; right now your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add system variable in enviroment for each user? Then you can use aliases like `%MYSPECIALFOLDER%\Department\Files\Drawings\NewPart.dwg`?
Each user will have their own environ setup, but your path always be correct